# Custome load Optional Configuration file into hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have read the online tutorial about Optional Configuration
https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/2011/en-US/8beb75da86691014a0229cf991cb67e4.html

I know that after I set the HYBRIS_OPT_CONFIG_DIR and put [2digit number]-local.properties file into this directory, Hybris will load these files automatically.

What I want to do is that, I set up several hybris work nodes as a cluster, and every node need a different configuration because every node's role is different, one is frontend, one is backend and one is data processor.

However, due to some reason, I have to set the same HYBRIS_OPT_CONFIG_DIR value for every node, so I want to know, if there is any way to let hybris load some of properties file in this directory.

For example, I put 10-local.properties and 20-local.properties, and one node only load 10-local.properties and one node will load both of them.

I know that I can implement configuration switch by set different value of HYBRIS_OPT_CONFIG_DIR, but I hope I can find another way.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old but maybe it will help someone in the future.

I see 3 potential solutions here:

1. Keep common config/local.properties with node type agnostic properties and store additional node type specific properties files in separate directories. Then set HYBRIS_OPT_CONFIG_DIR to a different directory to let hybris load additional props. E.g.

   ```
   /config/local.properties <- common props
   /config/frontend/10-local.properties <- additional frontend props
   /config/backend/10-local.properties <- additional backend props
   ```

Now setting `HYBRIS_OPT_CONFIG_DIR=/config/frontend` environment variable will make hybris load `/config/local.properties` AND `/config/frontend/10-local.properties`.

2. Use HYBRIS_RUNTIME_PROPERTIES env variable to point to an additional properties file. E.g. you could have

   ```
   /config/local.properties <- common props
   /config/frontend.properties <- additional frontend props
   /config/backend.properties <- additional backend props
   ```

Now setting `HYBRIS_RUNTIME_PROPERTIES=/config/frontend.properties`  environment variable will make hybris load `/config/local.properties` AND `/config/frontend.properties`.

3. Use `useconfig` system property to make hybris load a different properties file. In this case you need to setup props like this:

   ```
   /config/localfrontend.properties <- frontend props
   /config/localbackend.properties <- backend props
   ```

Setting `useconfig` system property (e.g. by using `-Duseconfig=frontend`) will make Hybris load ONLY `/config/localfrontend.properties` properties file.